# Click function not working as when called from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I had function as below being called when I click on a radio button "foo" and it works as expected when I clicked:

```
$("#foo").live("click", function () {
    if ($('input:radio[name=foo]:checked').val() == 'foo') {
        $.each(oneArray, function (key, value) {
            $("#foo1").append($("<option></option>")
                         .attr("value", key)
                         .text(value));
        });
        $.each(twoArray, function (key, value) {
            $("#foo2").append($("<option></option>")
                     .attr("value", key)
                     .text(value));
        });
    }
});
```

But it didn't worked when I did the following:

```
checkFoo(){ 
    $("#foo").click();
}
```

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: CheckFoo is a my own function to invoke the click on the radio button.... I got the answer with a bonus question and a -ve vote ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$("#foo").live("click", function () {...` use `$("#foo").live("change", function () {..`

Hope this help.